# How can I call other ' StatefulWidget ' or method which is named as MyDetailPage from the StatefulWidget named as MyHomePage?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Here I have created two 'StatefulWidget' named as MyHomePage &  MyDetailPage . Where the First StatefulWidget storing  Image, Appbar and the second StatefulWidget is trying to fetch the data from cloud firestore.

But now the question is "how can I call MyDetailPage class placed right nxt the MyHomePage class & where should I add the changes so that all the fetched data comes under the Image and Appbar.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(


      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children:<Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),

              Card(

                  child: Image.asset(
                    'images/picture_logo.jpg',
                    height: 120,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )

              ),
              Text(
                'Please Select your Preference!!',
                style:TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                  fontSize: 17.0,
                  color:Colors.black,
                  letterSpacing: 3.5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),

              AppBar(
                title: Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
              ),

                // Want to call MyDetailPage  under the AppBar.
                // What changes I should add here to call "MyDetailPage" class ?

            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDetailPageState createState() => new  _MyDetailPageState();
}

class _MyDetailPageState extends State<MyDetailPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(

        body:
        StreamBuilder(
    stream:  Firestore.instance.collection('client').snapshots(),
    builder: (context,snapshot){
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
            DocumentSnapshot client =snapshot.data.documents[index];
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                height: 300,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent,width: 2),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      
                        SizedBox(width: 10),

                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Name:- ${client['fname']}\n',),
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                            ],
                          ),
                        )

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
        },
      );
    },
    )

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to just place it under the appbar like this: `MyDetailPage()`

Comment: Remove the Scaffold from second page and call the page as a widget.. It may cause flex widget issue, listview under flex widget.. So provide boundary to the listview or use shrink wrap as true in listview.. And you don't need to use singlechildscrollview inside listview builder

Comment: @proversion. Can u pls explain me with the help of code because it's very difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 30.0,
      ),

      Card(
          child: Image.asset(
        'images/picture_logo.jpg',
        height: 120,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      )),
      Text(
        'Please Select your Preference!!',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
          fontSize: 17.0,
          color: Colors.black,
          letterSpacing: 3.5,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),

      AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),

      MyDetailPage(), // Added the class here

      // Want to call MyDetailPage  under the AppBar.
      // What changes I should add here to call "MyDetailPage" class ?
    ],
  )),
);
}
}

class MyDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_MyDetailPageState createState() => new _MyDetailPageState();
}

class _MyDetailPageState extends State<MyDetailPage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
//Rempved Scaffold and return a Container
return new Container(
  height: 300,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 10,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        height: 300,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent, width: 2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Name:- NAME\n',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```